# Identifying character variables and changing them to numeric in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with nearly 30,000 rows and 1935 variables(columns). Among these many are character variables (around 350). Now I can change data type of an individual column using `as.numeric` on it, but it is painful to search for columns which are character type and then apply this individually on them. I have tried writing a function using a loop but since the data size is huge, laptop is crashing.
Please help.

Comment: a `dput(head(dataset))` would help answering (is there factors or not, etc.)

Comment: (Well, 1935 columns may be too large, something along `dput(head(dataset[,5:15]))` could be easier to follow, adapt the range to include one or two column you wish to coerce.

Comment: Tired waiting a feedback so example: `sapply(colnames(iris), function(x) { if(is.character(paste(iris[1,x]))) { as.numeric(iris[,x]) } else { iris[,x] } }) ` will set NA if there's character which are non-numeric and coerce to numeric columns where the first element is a char. Maybe not the better way, but without a clue on the data, I think it is the safest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
take <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
which(take == FALSE)
```

identify which variables are numeric, but I don't know how extract automatically, so

```
apply(data[, c(putcolumnsnumbershere)], 1, as.character))
```

Comment: you're first line can be a problem if a column is a factor. In the last line, I believe you're looking for `is.character` rather than `as.character`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
sapply(your.data, typeof)
```

to create a vector of variable types, then use this vector to identify the character vector columns to be converted.