# Convert variables from character to numeric, but excluding one character variable

Tags: r, dataframe, char, type-conversion

**Problem**

Working with a data frame in R, I want to change variables represented as characters into variables represented as numbers (i.e. from class `chr` to `num`).

For an entire data set, this is a straightforward problem (different flavors of solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8596466/7983039), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251326/convert-data-frame-column-format-from-character-to-factor), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772279/converting-multiple-columns-from-character-to-numeric-format-in-r), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397986/identifying-character-variables-and-changing-them-to-numeric-in-r)). However, I have one variable that needs to stay as characters.

*Example Data*

Using this example data (`df`), let's say I want to change only `var1` from class `chr` to `num`, leaving `"chrOK"` as a `chr` variable. In my real data set, there are many variables to change, so manual approaches like `df$var1 = as.numeric(df$var1)` is too laborious.

```
df = data.frame(var1  = c("1","2","3","4"), 
                var2  = c(1,2,3,4),
                chrOK = c("rick", "summer","beth", "morty"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(df)

'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
$ var1 : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4"
$ var2 : num  1 2 3 4
$ chrOK: chr  "rick" "summer" "beth" "morty"
```

**Partial Solutions**

I've tried a several approaches that seem close, but don't do exactly what I want.

*Attempt 1 — introduces NAs*

Most of my columns are characters that should be numeric, like `"var1"`. So, using `apply()` to convert class works. However, this approach fails induces `NA` values in `"chrOK"`.

```
df = as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, function(x) as.numeric(x))) 

Warning message:
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
$ var1 : num  1 2 3 4
$ var2 : num  1 2 3 4
$ chrOK: num  NA NA NA NA
```

*Attempt 2 — split, convert, cbind*

Using `apply()` on the subset of `chr` variables, excluding `"chrOK"`, doesn't induce `NA`s, but requires using `cbind()` to re-include `"chrOK"`.

This solution is not ideal because `cbind()` results are hard to check for data mutations. (Also, `"chrOK"` is returned as a factor. Using `df = cbind(changed,as.character(unchanged))` doesn't work. [a])

```
changed = as.data.frame(apply(df[-(which(colnames(df)=="chrOK"))],2,function(x) as.numeric(x)))
unchanged = (df$chrOK)

df = cbind(changed,unchanged)

str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
$ var1     : num  1 2 3 4
$ var2     : num  1 2 3 4
$ unchanged: Factor w/ 4 levels "beth","morty",..: 3 4 1 2 #[a]
```

*Attempt 3 — correct subset, but error when converting*

Using `setdiff()` I get the subset of `chr` class variables excluding `"chrOK".

```
df[setdiff(names(df[sapply(df,is.character)]),"chrOK")]
  var1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
```

But trying to plug this into an apply function, so that only the subset is changed from `chr` to `num` returns an error (see [b]).

```
 apply(as.numeric(df[setdiff(names(df[sapply(df,is.character)]),"chrOK")]),
       2,function(x) as.numeric(x))

Error in apply(as.numeric(df[setdiff(names(df[sapply(df, is.character)]),  :
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' #[b]
```

**Questions**

- What is the best solution for converting a data frame's character variables to numeric, while excluding a specified subset?
- Which of my attempts is the right path or is there a better approach?
- [bonus] What mechanism causes the unexpected results at [a] and [b], above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `type.convert` from `base R` by looping over the columns of the dataset and assign it back to the original object

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))
str(df)
#'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ var1 : int  1 2 3 4
#$ var2 : int  1 2 3 4
#$ chrOK: chr  "rick" "summer" "beth" "morty"
```

The `type.convert` is calling a C code i.e. `C_typeconvert`

---

The reason why the OP's solutions are getting NAs are

1) `apply` converts the `data.frame` to `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only a single `class`.  Suppose there is a single `character` element in the `matrix`, it converts the whole into `character`.

2) Using `as.numeric` with `apply` is problematic as the 'chrOK' is already a `character` class column.  Whenever `as.numeric` is applied to non-numeric strings, it converts it NA.

3) The OP used the same `apply` in the second method.  It is described as in 1.

Comment: This works! How does this "know" to change var1 but not chrOK?

Comment: @Danielle The `type.convert` is calling an internal C code and it would be checking whether the elements are numbers or character before converting to respective classes.

Comment: You explain that `as.numeric` will convert characters to NA, so why does using it with `apply` only change chrOK into NAs but not var1?

Comment: @Danielle  Because all others are numbers i.e. 0:9 while the elements in 'chrOK' is 'a-z'